# Android - notifyDataSetChanged not working with Custom View

Tags: android, custom-adapter

I have a list of questions, and on each item there is a yes and no checkbox.  This is created using an abstract class (because there are lots of lists), a child class, and the array adapter.  Here is the abstract class code creating the list:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  List<Question> questions = getQuestions(1L);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);
  items = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.items);
  adapter = new QuestionsAdapter(this, getCurrentContext(), questions, 1L, getDbData());
  items.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

Here is the QuestionsAdapter:

```
public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View row = convertView;
  if (row == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_questions, parent, false);
    holder = new QuestionHolder();
    holder.question = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.question);
    holder.yes = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.yes);
    holder.no = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.no);
    row.setTag(holder);
  } else {
    holder = (QuestionHolder) row.getTag();
  }
  Question question = questions.get(position);
  holder.question.setText(question.getQuestion());    
  setStateCheckboxes(holder, question);
  holder.yes.setTag(getItem(position));
  holder.no.setTag(getItem(position));
  holder.yes.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listen);
  holder.no.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listen);
  return row;
}
```

I have to create the holder to be able to have a listview with checkboxes.  Up to this point, everything is working fine.

I then have a view for each element on the list.  It is very basic:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  dbData = new DbData(this);
  this.setContentView(R.layout.single_question);
  CheckBox yes = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.yes_single);
  CheckBox no = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.no_single);
}
```

In this view I can change the status of the checkboxes.  This change is reflected in the db, but when I return to the main list, it is only reflected on refresh.  I have overridden the onRestart():

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
  // Change this
  questions = getQuestions(1L);
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  super.onRestart();
}
```

The adapter is pulling the data from the questions ArrayList, so I am repolling it and the notifying the adapter that the data has changed, but this does not change my view.  If I refresh the view, then the current state of everything is updated.  I know this is a long question, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onResume() method to call through to notifyDataSetChanged.

You will need code to manage whether the adapter has been created. You don't want to be calling it too early in the process or you run the risk of exceptions.

Generally I do this through a method that is responsible for initialising the adapter and adding it to the listview, which makes it safer to call this irrespective of whether the activity/fragment is starting for the first time or being returned to from another activity (e.g. through the back button), as well as avoiding recreating the adapter or replacing an existing adapter on the listview.

Also better to call the super.onRestart() before your own code.